# how to match nodes AND child nodes (same name) in xsl:template

Tags: xslt, svg, layer, inkscape

I have an inkscape svg file.

simplified version:

```
<svg>
    <g inkscape:label="layerA">
        <g inkscape:label="layerB"/>
    </g>
    <g inkscape:label="layerC">
        <g inkscape:label="layerD"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want to extract the layers A (and B) and D.

This works for layer A which is directly under the root element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
>

<!-- Auto intend -->
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<!-- Copy every other node, element, attribute -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Do not copy any other group -->
<xsl:template match="svg:g"/>

<!-- Copy all matching groups -->
<xsl:template match="svg:g[@inkscape:label='layerA']|svg:g[@inkscape:label='layerD']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

But it does not copy layer D.

So my question is: How can I match not only the nodes directly under root, but under another "g" element.

Comment: Your "simplified" version of the input is not well-formed XML and does not match your stylesheet - which makes it difficult to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of :

```
<!-- Do not copy any other group -->
<xsl:template match="svg:g"/>
```

do:

```
<xsl:template match="svg:g">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="svg:g"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Otherwise your next template:

```
<!-- Copy all matching groups -->
<xsl:template match="svg:g[@inkscape:label='layerA']|svg:g[@inkscape:label='layerD']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

will never be applied to layer D.

Comment: Thanks.
It works.

But I have no clue why. :)

Are my comments even right?
Does the second `xsl:template` mean _"do not copy"_, because there is no `xsl:copy` command?
If so: How does this template influence the lest template?

Sorry, I am completely new to xsl. :)

Comment: You need to understand the [XSLT processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model), which works recursively. When you have a template that does nothing, then recursion stops there. So the processor never gets to layer D, because it's stopped at layer C.

Comment: P.S. We are assuming here that you need the *identity transform* template  (your first template) for some other nodes not shown in your input example. Otherwise your structure of  *rule/exception to the rule/exception to the exception* could be simplified, as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select=".//svg:g[@inkscape:label='layerA' or @inkscape:label='layerD']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML** (with added namespace declarations to make it well-formed) document:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
    <g inkscape:label="layerA">
        <g inkscape:label="layerB"/></g>
    <g inkscape:label="layerC">
        <g inkscape:label="layerD"/></g>
</svg>
```

**produces (what I guess is) the wanted, correct result**:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
   <g inkscape:label="layerA">
      <g inkscape:label="layerB"/>
   </g>
   <g inkscape:label="layerD"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for your answers!

I just want to addan alternative way to get to my goal (a png export with a subset of the layers within an svg).

https://github.com/wader/inkmake

The *inkfile* looks like this:

```
output.png input.svg -* +layerA +layerB +layerD
```

This saves me the trouble of genarationg many new svg files before exporting them to png.

But thanks again.